# Android Fragment, how to use both v4 and app.fragment in same viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have two modules, one have fragments with support.v4 library and another with app.fragment. I need to use both fragments in one viewpager. Is there a way to use both fragment types in same viewpager? Because module which built using app.fragment is google source code (huge one, if I would have to rewrite it).. Thanks in advance, any ideas helps.